# Why is bismillah al Rahman al Raheem in the beginning of the surahs?

Tags: asma-ul-husna, knowing-islam

I'm sorry, but I'm just curious on why we say Bismillah al Rahman al Raheem in the beginning of the surahs we read and not let's say for example Bismillah al Azeem? I'm sorry I don't mean it to be disrespectful in any way possible but I'm just curious.

Comment: If the question was taken wrong you should edit and explain more instead of deleting it.

Comment: ياsr that's not what I meant. I didn't mean the phrase is the name of Allah (swt). Calm down guys. I didn't mean it in a disrespectful way and if you thought that the question wasn't good or anything then just delete it or report it so that you won't see it. It was worded differently from what I was trying to make it sound.

Comment: A simple answer would be because Allah revealed the given sentence and not any other. You may ask whether other options are valid.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with an explanation of the meaning of the Basmalah (Bismillah ar-Rahman ar-Raheem)

> بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ

actually means in English something like:

> In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful. (see for example 1:1 https://quranx.com/1.1)

It is a sentence which is used to praise Allah and we are recommended to recite when starting the qur'an recitation and it is a well discussed matter among scholars whether or not it is part of the beginning of 113 out of 114 surahs in the qur'an.
This sentence actually contain two of the names of Allah (beside the name "Allah" itself) ٱلرَّحْمَٰن "the Entirely Merciful" and ٱلرَّحِيم "the Especially Merciful".

Note that praising Allah by starting with or in  his name, was known before Islam as the qur'an quotes it in the speech of two former prophets:

- > And [Noah] said, "Embark therein; **in the name of Allah** is its course and its anchorage. Indeed, my Lord is Forgiving and Merciful." (11:41 https://quranx.com/11.41)
- > Indeed, it is from Solomon, and indeed, it reads: '**In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful**, (27:30 https://quranx.com/27.30)

Answer (score 1):

It is because that is how Allah revealed the Quran.

Open a mushaf, and you will find the basmalah as it is in the beginning of every Surah. It is part of the Quran. We cannot change it anymore than we can change any word in any Surah.